# rewrite wordpress page url for seo friendly query strings

Tags: url-rewriting

I have a wordpress page with Url Slug `location`. 
I want to pass a parameter to this page using the format : 
`http://mywpsite.com/location/mylocation`

where `mylocation` will be the parameter passed to `zipcode` variable.
It can be either an integer or string like`http//mywpsite.com/location/atlanta`
or `http://mywpsite.com/location/345005`

I tried using the wordpress rewrite api but it didn't work even after flushing rewrite rules from both code and wp-admin.

Below is the code I tried in my themes `function.php`:

```
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array','my_insert_rewrite_rules' );
add_filter( 'query_vars','my_insert_query_vars' );
add_action( 'wp_loaded','my_flush_rules' );

// flush_rules() if our rules are not yet included
function my_flush_rules(){
    $rules = get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );

//        echo "<pre><code>".  print_r($rules)."</pre></code>";
//        die("SHIVGRE");

    if ( ! isset( $rules['(location)\/([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)\/?(\d*)?$'] ) ) {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }
}

// Adding a new rule
function my_insert_rewrite_rules( $rules )
{

    print_r($rules);die("BBBB");
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['(location)\/([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)\/?(\d*)?$'] = 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&zipcode=$matches[2]';#&page=$match[3]
    return $newrules + $rules;
}

// Adding the id var so that WP recognizes it
function my_insert_query_vars( $vars )
{    
    array_push($vars, 'zipcode');
    return $vars;
}
```

It didn't work for some reason. Right now my urls work fine with `http://mywpsite.com/location?zipcode=atlanta` or `http://mywpsite.com/location?zipcode=345005`

but whenever I try hitting this `http://mywpsite.com/location/atlanta` then I get redirected to 404 page and my `location' page template is not even called.

It did work with `http://mywpsite.com/location/345005` but I receive the `zipcode` in `paged` parameter instead.

Any help would be much appreciated.